# I want to tell you something about me / myself

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

What is the difference between the following sentences?( It sounds like both are ok)

> I want to tell you something about me.
>
> I want to tell you something about myself.

Sometimes apparently it is possible to say

> It is about me, not you.

or

> Tell me about yourself. (in a interview)

but we cannot replace with one another in the examples above.

I'd like to ask what the rule is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They were talking about me" and "It took me five minutes to tell them all about myself. "It's about me, not you" means the information concerns personally you, not anyone else. As for a particular rule, I think it's obvious that anyone can tell about themselves (here "about myself") and they can tell anyone about you, me, him etc. Hope it helped.

Comment: In short, you can say to someone: She told them about me. But in speaking about yourself, myself is better.